# DNS Glue Records and Dedicated IP Address

Tags: nameserver, glue-record

I have five domains and am on a shared hosting. I decided to purchase a dedicated IP address with my hosting provider today. I am also using their NS servers. My domain names are also on different domain service providers. One of my domain provider has the option to create a GLUE record.

With this, I wanted to clarify with experts and pros about this since I have been searching around the net and also ask my hosting provider but doesnt get a clearer answer yet.

1. Is creating a GLUE record similar with NS servers?
2. Where and when can I use a GLUE record?
3. Since I can attach my dedicated IP to the GLUE records, does this mean that the GLUE records I create will actually resolve to the correct website?
4. Would my website still work even if I replace the nameservers with the GLUE records I created?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use your domain providers name servers to server as your name servers.  Just configure your domain(s) with an A record for the website.

You only need to configure glue records if your are running your own name server.  Even then you only to configure them, if the nameserver's domain is the domain or a sub-domain that you are configuring.  (Only one of your five domains should need you to configure glue records. The others should use the name server domains, of the domain that requires glue records.

> 1. Is creating a GLUE record similar with NS servers?

Yes, the GLUE record provide the IP address for the name servers. It is necessary to provide them if the name server's name is a sub-domain of the domain they are a name server for.

For example `ns1.example.com` needs a glue record when it is the name server for `example.com`.  However, if it is the name server for `example.net` a glue record does not need to be provided to the domain registrar.

> 2. Where and when can I use a GLUE record?

You don't use the GLUE record.  The resolver library uses them to locate the IP address of the corresponding name servers.  When you query the `com.` name servers for the name servers for `example.com` they will provide both the name `ns1.example.com` and an A record for `ns1.example.com`.  This address may not be correct, as it is the address configured as the GLUE record for `example.com`.

> 3. Since I can attach my dedicated IP to the GLUE records, does this mean that the GLUE records I create will actually resolve to the correct website?

The GLUE records should have different IP addresses, and point to your name servers.  They will always be non-authoritative addresses.  It would be unusual that your web domain and name server domain would be the same.  If they were, they might be use to access your name server.  However, the correct lookup would be to use a GLUE record to connect to a name server and get an authoritative address.

> 4. Would my website still work even if I replace the name servers with the GLUE records I created?

As noted in the previous answer, they might work.  However, any clients wanting authoritative address may refuse to connect.